# How does UIImageJPEGRepresentation work?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagejpegrepresentation

I have this line of code

```
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImage, 0.8)
```

and I was wondering if it adjusts the height and width of the image or just the size by decreasing the quality?

Answer (score 2):

It just decreases the quality.

```
func UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_ image: UIImage!,
                         _ compressionQuality: CGFloat) -> NSData!
```

Source:  [UIImageJPEGRepresentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageJPEGRepresentation)